# How to change default root directory in apache2 from /var/www/ to /home/ubuntu/project/

Tags: django, apache

I have configured apache2 to run my django application on ubuntu server but I'm facing issue while uploading images at my desired directory, it goes into /var/www/ directory.

I have edited  '000-default.conf' file in apache2 with the directory I want the webserver to take as root directory for my application as bellow.

```
DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/project/

<Directory /home/ubuntu/project/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

and /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<Directory /home/ubuntu/project/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

After this change I have restarted the web server. 
Still when my django application uploads any images it goes in /var/www/ directory. I don't understand why its happening even if I have changed the apache root directory from /var/www/ to /home/ubuntu/project/

Please suggest ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the **DocumentRoot** setting in your **httpd.conf** file. Chances are it will be under something like **/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf**

There just change this:

```
<Directory "/var/www">
```

to this:

```
<Directory "/home/ubuntu/project">
```

Now restart your apache service:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: Hi, thanks @Timo but I dont have this "/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf" directory , but as I have mentioned above "/etc/apache2/apache2.conf" in this file I have made the same changes as you described, but still its not affecting the change even after restarting apache2

Comment: That is akward. Do you tried to open the httpd.conf with a text editor or, its not an directory. Did that help?

Comment: I mean I don't have that httpd.conf file as per your mentioned directory path. I dont have that /conf/ directory even under apache2.

Comment: Try find -name "httpd.conf" and look if you find the file path.

Answer (score 0):

The upload directory will be set by your Django app, not by your Apache config.

Check your [`MEDIA_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#media-root) setting.

Comment: Cool. I know that but just one query, till now I was not using full path for my media directory. When I gave full directory path then images getting uploaded at desired place but when I didn't define full path for media then its going into /var/www directory. First I need to know if I dont defined media root why its going into /var/www. It should ideally give an error saying 'media' doesn't exists in your project directory.

Comment: Why apache always going into /var/www directory for uploading files, even though we haven't included that path in apache config file.

Comment: You query is too complicated for the comments. Please update your original question, include the relevant Django code, and say where your Django project is located.

Comment: Basically when you run your django app on server without using apache or any webserver it runs perfectly fine, uploaded files goes into specific desired directory defined in MEDIA_ROOT but when you use apache to server your django app I don't understand why apache looks for /var/www directory to put uploaded files.

Comment: I think thats the key we need full directory path to be define in settings for MEDIA_ROOT if you don't define that it goes into /var/www. Just little curious about from where its actually taking this /var/www path to store files.